# Error occured only when validation option is added : Numpy arrays is not the size the model expected

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning

The weird point is that I got this "checking model input error: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected." only when I add validation dataset option (if I remove validation part in this code, it works).
Clearly, entered (to my knowledge) suitable validation data shape as well as training dataset. I just entered exact same form of validation dataset with training dataset.

training/validation input form is as follows.

partial_x_train / partial_estendo / partial_y_train : (7000,1) numpy array
x_val / estendo_val / y_val : (3000,1) numpy array

What I already tried(2 ways)

1) the other post in stackoverflow recommended to use "np.array()" for the case where keras model cannot recognize non-numpy array input. However, it doesn't work in my case. I don't think this is the solution for me.

2) I thought it is mainly due to improper parenthesis at first. so I just tried to alter that part. but Neither of them works. (Even when I enter the training dataset as validation dataset)

----------skip : just creating dataset -----------

```
def create_mean(inputs):
    x = inputs
    x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='mean_output')(x)
    return x


def create_std(inputs):
    x = inputs
    x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='softplus', name='var_output')(x)
    return x


def generatesecmodel(name):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(second_input,))
    mean_branch = create_mean(inputs)
    var_branch = create_std(inputs)
    label_mean = Input(shape=(1,))
    model2 = Model(inputs=[inputs, label_mean], outputs=[mean_branch, var_branch])

    loss = 0.5 * K.log(var_branch + 1e-6) + 0.5 * K.square(label_mean - mean_branch) / (var_branch + 1e-6)

    model2.add_loss(loss)
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.1)
    model2.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=None)

    model2.fit([np.concatenate((partial_estendo, partial_x_train), axis=1), partial_y_train], epochs=num_epochs,
               batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=([np.concatenate((estendo_val, x_val), axis=1), y_val]))


model = generatesecmodel('test')
```

Error message is as follows
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[ 1.60455704e-04, -9.37487497e-01],
       [ 9.99757528e-01,  1.45345668e-01],
       [ 9.99548554e-01,  2.66093564e-02],
       ...,
       [ 9.98771310e-01, -1.19436635e-01],
       [ 6.7000...